# Model Binder: invalid value in property makes model null

Tags: asp.net-core

I have the following ASP.NET Core controller action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Model model) { }
```

The Model is the following:

```
public class Model {
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public Int32? Age { get; set; }
}
```

I then, using Angular, tried to post an invalid model:

```
model = { name: "John", age: "Ab }
```

On my controller the model becomes null. If I use `age: 30` the model has the values defined.

If age has an invalid value shouldn't the model be defined and Age has the Int32? default value, e.g., null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. The `Int32? Age` accepts a null value but not an invalid value. The posted model with invalid age value tries to convert the value to an interger and this fails because the value is not an interger.

With the following json: `{ name: "John", age: "Ab }` the ModelState contains two errors:

```
Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: \
Unexpected end when deserializing object
```

Giving a correct string value `{ name: "John", age: "test"}`the ModelState contains one error:

```
Could not convert string to integer: test
```

Comment: Yes, agree but why making the model null when that happens? Why not only the property and keep the other properties defined?

Comment: The json cannot be converted to the model. Simply because the json is not valid for the model. So there is no partial deserialize, it complete fails.